# Meaning of predict.fixed and predict.Subject values in 'predict' function of nlme

Tags: r, mixed-model, prediction, lme4-nlme

As discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39407395/meaning-of-predict-fixed-and-predict-subject-in-predict-function-of-nlme?noredirect=1#comment66226075_39407395) SO thread, I am using the `predict` function in `nlme` to derive predictions for each participants' fourth day score in my own dataset, based on their previous scores and a mixed-effects model. So I am wondering which column of predicted values to use.

Here is an example of how the `predict` function works using the `Orthodont` dataset and code supplied by the nlme package manual

```
library(nlme)
fm1 <- lme(distance ~ age, Orthodont, random = ~ age | Subject)
    newOrth <- data.frame(Sex = c("Female","Female","Female","Female","Male","Male"),
                          age = c(15, 20, 10, 12, 2, 4),
                          Subject = c("M01","M01","F30","F30","M04","M04"))
    ## The  Orthodont  data has *no*  F30 , so predict  NA  at level 1 :
    predict(fm1, newOrth, level = 0:1)
```

So if we specify `levels` as `0:1` the `predict` function gives two columns of predicted values for each participant. One is the marginal predictions, when we 'set the random effects to 0' or 'average across random effects'. The other column is the conditional or subject-specific random effects for each individual, where we 'hold the random effects constant'

If the population estimates are for the average subject, why are they all different? i.e. in what sense are they average?

I have been trying to get a sense of this for a while. Are the extrapolated *population* predictions for each subject derived from some combination of fixed group-level effects **and** from fitting a slope *for each individual* from the previous measurement occassions and then using that 'individual slope + fixed group effect' to come up with the estimated value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it works as follows, the `predict.fixed` column only uses the fixed effects from your model. We can view these with `summary(fm1)`:

```
Fixed effects: distance ~ age 
                Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept) 16.761111 0.7752460 80 21.620377       0
age          0.660185 0.0712533 80  9.265333       0
```

As you specified a different age for each subject in your dataframe `age = c(15, 20, 10, 12, 2, 4)` the resulting predictions are made `16.761111 + 0.660185 * newOrth$age`. The differences are a result of differences in age.

As you noted the `predict.Subject` column includes the subject specific random effects. You can retrieve these with the command `ranef(fm1)`. You will see that subject `M01` has a random intercept of `1.0515830` and a random slope of `0.215684556`. So the first value of `predict.Subject` is `16.761111 + 1.0515830 + 0.660185 * (15 + 0.215684556)`. Although the second line is the same subject with the same random effects, you've specified a different age for this subject (20 instead of 15) so the difference is the age coefficient `0.660185` multiplied by the 5 year difference in age. The second prediction in `predict.Subject` is `16.761111 + 1.0515830 + 20*(0.660185 + 0.215684556)`.

I hope that I understood your question and that this answer resolves your interpretation issues.

Comment: Thank you Niek. That `ranef()` command is very useful, and thankyou for the explanation of how these predicted values are derived.

Comment: Actually @Niek now I think about it I still don't understand, because if we held age constant (say at 15) and used your equation (i.e. an additive composite of the fixed effects) wouldn't the marginal prediction be the same for every participant? I know this cannot be the case because in my own data I have obtained marginal predictions for each individual at the same value of the predictor variable and their predicted scores are not all the same. Surely each individual's previous scores must inform the predicted value somehow *in combination with* the sample's fixed effects.

Comment: Actually sorry ignore that last comment. I had included Covariates which were different for each participant. If I run the model without these then the marginal predictions are the same for all participants who belong to the same group. Thank you again, this has been very enlightening.